# how to resolve Cannot GET / in a kubernetes deployment?

Tags: node.js, docker, kubernetes

I have an node.js application called "process-core" which has the main logic to run another node.js app called "page-core".Through "Process-core" I am deploying the distribution folder(static contents) of the "page-core" application.I am deploying this using kubernetes.

dockerfile used to build image for "process-core"

```
FROM node:8

RUN mkdir -p usr/src/app

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . .

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN npm install

CMD [ "npm","start" ]
```

my server.js goes like this-

```
var express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
var router = express.Router();
var request = require('request');

var api = require('./server/api.js')

const base_url = 'http://localhost:8080/api/';
const static_dir = '/home/vignesh/page-core-devbranch/dist';  // location of 
const assets_dir = path.join(__dirname + '/server/assets/');      dist folder
const tools_dir = path.join(__dirname + '/server/tools/');
const index_file = path.join(static_dir + '/index.html');

/* static */
app.use(cors())
app.use(express.static(static_dir));
app.use('/assets', express.static(assets_dir));
app.use('/tools', express.static(tools_dir));



/* listen */
app.listen(5000);
```

node.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    node: test
  name: nodetest
spec:
  ports:
  - nodePort: 30000
    port: 5000
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 5000
  selector:
    node: test
  type: NodePort

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: nodetest
  labels:
    node: test
spec:
  containers:
  - name: node-test
    image: suji165475/devops-sample:processcore
    ports:
    - containerPort: 5000
```

When I hit http://206.189.22.155:30000/ i get an error saying Cannot GET /

Comment: try sending request to `http://206.189.22.155:5000`

Answer (score 1):

```
FROM node:8

RUN mkdir -p usr/src/app

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . .

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN npm install

EXPOSE 5000

CMD [ "npm","start" ]
```

You have not expose port from docker image in docker file please add one line as `EXPOSE 5000` to open the container port 5000 from docker container.

Comment: do we specify the command "npm start" in the docker file or the kubenretes yaml file itself?

Comment: like command: [ "/bin/bash", "-ce", "npm start" ] at the end of the yaml file?

Comment: yes you can specify in both file dockerfile as well as in kubernetes yaml file

Comment: i did what you said but i am still getting an error saying Cannot GET /  at url http://206.189.22.155:30000/

Comment: basically this should deploy the dist folder of the page-core application

Comment: are you sure with npm start it will run application. check if your pod is ready condition.

Comment: but its not doing that!!

Comment: i think express is not able to hjandle request or something like that. no much idea.